# Java script works fine with number but error 80020101 with variable...why?

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

My code is to get the plenty of information from the website so called crawling and I'd like to have your advice since java script attempts not to accept the value by variable.

The error code is 80020101 but it works perfect when I change strValue to the 10-digit number instead of varable.

```
 Dim strValue
        
 For Each ele1 In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(1).Children
   ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(1).Value = ele1.Value
   strValue = ele1.Value
   Call ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript:doCompletion(strValue, 1)", "javascript")
 Next ele1
```

This java script is working in 1st ComboBox with activating next ComboBox to show the relative lists. I need around 100 inputs to get more than 20,000 lists so it's very crucial to me to use variable on the code below.

```
Call ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript:doCompletion(strValue, 1)", "javascript")
```

The value of ele1.Value is 10-digit such as 2644000000 or 2514000000, and the javascript works perfect when I replace strValue to 2644000000 or 2514000000.

Please advice or give a tip how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages.

Comment: Everything in quotes is seen as string by VBA. `"javascript:doCompletion(strValue, 1)"` will pass the string `strValue`, not the content of the variable.. You need something like `"javascript:doCompletion(" & strValue & ", 1)"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointing out !!! I give you Thumbs Up.

Comment: I'm in favor of FunThomas's comment. I think it can solve your issue. VBA doesn't replace variable names with their values within strings. `&` operator is used to force string concatenation of two expressions. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) for more details.